# Pentaho Data Integration De-normalize many row values as field names

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, denormalization

I am reading data from a survey in a table that has 3 fields: 
- record
- question
- answer

in each row for every record there are many questions with the relative answer:

```
|record|question|answer|
------------------------
|1     |q1.     |a1.   |
|1     |q2.     |a2.   |
|2     |q1.     |a1.   |
|2     |q2.     |a2.   |
```

What i want to do in Pentaho is transform this table to one where i have the record field and then each question should be a field so that rows contain record id and answer values:

```
|record|q1      |q2.   |
------------------------
|1     |a1      |a2    |
|2     |a1      |a2    |
```

I would do it with the de-normalization step, but in my case i have a lot and possibly changing questions, so i was wondering if there is an automatic way to have the values in the input question field mapped to the output field names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with Metadata injection to inject these values in runtime!!!